# Calculating overlapping rgba values

Tags: html, css, rgba

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/CPK7L/2/

```
.example {

  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 25px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-right: -30px;
}

.example2 {

  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 25px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

As you can see, the first element's right-border is overlapping the second element's left-border. When this happens, their rgba values stack up making the right-border appear darker.

How to calculate the alpha value needed for the right-border, if I want that border to appear its "original" color when it overlaps the second element's left-border?

Comment: why not just add border-left:none to the second one so there is no border to overlap? That way you wouldn't have the triangles appearing.

Comment: I just made that up to use it as an example. I'm not really looking for a css solution. What I'm interested in is the math that goes into calculating what rgba would make the border appear it's original color (not minding any triangles created in the process).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, is your inclusion of semi-opaque backgrounds intentional? The box model on the inline-block elements means that your background and border on each item are already getting multiplied - is this intentional to the question or a mistake? 
If a mistake and you're just asking how to get 2 semi-transparent objects overlaid to get to 0.5 opacity where the second one is 0.3 opacity (so X + 0.3 = 0.5) you need to use 0.28. 
0.29 means 0.71 light is getting through. Your second item is set to 0.3 opacity which lets through 70% of the remaining 71% light. 70% of 71 is as close to 50 as you'll get.

If you needed to include the backgrounds you'd do something similar
item 1: background 50% + border 50% = 75% opacity.
item 2: background 30% + border 30% = 51% opacity.
required border-right on item1 to get 75% opacity for all 4 colors = 50%(div1 bg) + X(div1 border-right) + 51%(div2 background and border).
The problem here is for [50% + X + 51%] to equal [50% + 50%] X would have to be a minus number, which you can't have.